# Does blockwise allow iteration over out-of-core arrays?

Tags: arrays

The [blockwise docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.blockwise) mention that with `concatenate=False`:

> In the case of a contraction the passed function should expect an iterable of blocks on any array that holds that index.

My question then is whether or not there is a fundamental limitation that would prohibit this "iterable of blocks" from loading the blocks one at a time rather than keeping them all in a `list` (i.e. in memory).  Is this possible?  It does not look like `blockwise` works this way now, but I am wondering if it could:

```py
import dask.array as da
import operator

# Create an array and write to disk
x = da.random.random(size=(10, 6), chunks=(5, 3))
da.to_zarr(x, '/tmp/x.zarr', overwrite=True)
x = da.from_zarr('/tmp/x.zarr')
y = x.T

def fn(x, y):
    print(type(x), type(x[0]))
    x = np.concatenate(x, axis=1)
    y = np.concatenate(y, axis=0)
    return np.matmul(x, y)

da.blockwise(fn, 'ik', x, 'ij', y, 'jk', concatenate=False, dtype='float').compute(scheduler='single-threaded')
# <class 'list'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Is it possible for these lists to be generators instead?

Answer (score 0):

This was true very early on in Dask, but we switched to concrete lists eventually.  Today a task does not start until all of its dependency tasks are available in memory.

Given the context of your question I'm guessing that you're running up against memory issues with tensordot style applications.  The memory use of tensordot style applications depends heavily on chunk structure.  I encourage you to look at this issue, and especially at the talk referenced in the first post: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2225